# Text Align Center in Chrome (webkit)

Tags: css, google-chrome

Any idea why `text-align: center` doesn't center the text within the table cells? But `text-align: -webkit-center` does?

The reason why `display: table-cell` is applied is to have `vertical-align` to work. Removing it is not a solution and doesn't answer my question.

```css
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
.column {
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    /*text-align: -webkit-center;*/
    border: 1px solid gray;
    float: left;
}
span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
span:before {
    content: "text"
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column">
        <span></span>        
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <span></span>        
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <span></span>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because you are using `display: table-cell`

Comment: You just need to remove `display: table-cell` http://jsfiddle.net/fr5o21vp/

Comment: @Morpheus Yeah, the question is why in ... table-cell?

Comment: The reason why I am using `table-cell` is the `vertical-align` to work.

Comment: @Blix in that case you need to move `display: table-cell` to `.column`

Comment: @Morpheus: If I will apply table-cell to the .column, the with will not work. But more than that, I wonder why `text-align:center` is not working? But the `-webkit-center` yes? These should be equivalent. Is it a webkit bug?

Comment: Using `display: table-cell` without `display: table` on parent element is same as using `<td>` without `<table>`, http://jsfiddle.net/m9k7drxt/

Comment: @Morpheus: to place table display into the parent `wrapper` is not a solution. But why `-webkit-center` works? Try to play with the full code on jsfiddle.

Comment: @Blix, I have already tried and don't know why `-webkit-center` is working

Comment: @Morpheus: Yes, that is why this question was posted :)). But yet, many people were trying to answer without even understanding the full issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't with `display: table-cell` but the nature of the `span` element.

Please note that the `text-align` property in CSS is used for aligning the inner content of **block-level elements**.

The HTML `span` tag is an inline-level element. Hence, it doesn't apply by default to inline-level elements and therefore you have to use browser-specific CSS i.e. `text-align: -webkit-center`.

*Sources:*

CSS Tricks Almanac - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align/

W3Schools - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

Comment: @ Bhojendra Nepal: The same applies to FF.